# generating a C# code from a XML representation of a UML sequence diagramm

Tags: c#, uml, sequence-diagram

I have a XML respresention of a UML sequence diagram. Could someone please tell how one can generate a C# code(Classes) based on this XML.

Any information could be helpfull for me

thanks !

Comment: Where is the UML sequence diagram generated from?

Comment: Could you give us an example how this XML file looks like?

Comment: [Here](https://bian.org/servicelandscape/v4.5%20Candidate_files/_17_0_4_1_13d303b9_1381418491186_21071_6140.jpg) you find the Sequence diagramm. It's associated with two XML : [XML1](https://bian.org/servicelandscape/index_files/xml/_17_0_4_1_13d303b9_1381418479602_741636_5944.xml) and  [XML2](https://bian.org/servicelandscape/index_files/xml/_17_0_4_1_13d303b9_1381418491186_21071_6140.xml)

Comment: How could one create ANYTHING based on a single SD?